# Prevent scroll jumping in CKEditor and TinyMCE Inline editors on Chrome on dialog close

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, ckeditor, tinymce

I'm having issue specifically in chrome (52.0.2743.116, havent tried other versions) where after closing any of the dialogs in CKEditor or TinyMCE inline modes (link, table, colour picker etc) the page will scroll back to the top. This behaviour doesn't occur in Firefox, and I haven't tried IE.

The problem should be able to be reproduced in the ckeditor example [here.](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html) To reproduce, select one of the long columns at the bottom, and scroll down such that the top of the div is a fair bit offscreen. Now click the Link button and press cancel, the page should snap to the top of the div.

Any ideas on how to fix this, whether it be a JS hack or just a simple configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Next hack will help, just add to /CKEditor/config.js

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    ev.editor.on('dialogHide', function() {
        let height = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
        window.setTimeout(function() { window.scroll(0, height); }, 0);
    })
});
```